# How to convert xml to html using allure report framework

Tags: allure

Im using allure reporting with maven and testng
after test running I have xml.file with report result, can anyone explain me flow to convert it to html?

Comment: Doesn't allure render an HTML file? TestNG sure does.

Comment: i dont know how to implement it

Comment: From allure docs: "Once the XML files have been created by the adapter, you can generate an Allure report using one of the following tools: (list of plugins and command line tool foolows). "https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki#generating-a-report

Comment: Xml file of what allure report or testng report ?

Comment: Folliw the above link then

Comment: Now Im able to generate html report but there is no info about test run, instead of it I have some report about dependencies and other useless stuff for me

Answer (score 0):

Add below in case you do not have this in your pom.xml.

```
<reporting>
      <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
               <resultsPattern>${allure.results_pattern}</resultsPattern>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </reporting>
```

Then, re-run your test and run this command, 
mvn site -Dallure.results_pattern=allure-results

This will create a site folder under which you should get allure-maven-plugin.html. This is what you want i think.